Linking a button to a part of a web page from an ejs partials(nav)
I am unable to link a button on my nav bar in an ejs template to a part of one of my web pages
I have been trying to link a button in my nav bar to a part of my webpage, there are different web pages but the nav and footer are the same in all, but when i use the id linking method, it works only when I am on the page having the part i want to scroll to, and i tried using this method i pasted in the picture, my web page is showing cannot get views/index.ejs
 <nav>
        <a class="unDec" href="/">
            <h3 class="logo">Blogit</h3>
        </a>
        <div class="post-user">
            <a href="../views/index.ejs/#createPost">
                <input class="post-button" type="submit" value="Create Posts">
             </a>

image showing my code editor to check the path

Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you

Your HTML is invalid. An <input> element is not allowed inside an <a>

To reference sections on the same page the href attribute only needs the #id of the element.
There is an example of this on the mdn page of anchor tags:

Linking to an element on the same page
<!-- <a> element links to the section below -->
<p><a href="#Section_further_down">Jump to the heading below</a></p>
<!-- Heading to link to -->
<h2 id="Section_further_down">Section further down</h2>


But I don't really understand why you have an input inside the a tag. If you only need a button to jump to a section of the page, just use the a tag and style it so it looks like a button:


body {
  height: 200vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .3s ease;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  &:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 1px lightsalmon;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
  }
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background: rgb(200, 255, 100);
}
<a href="#someSection">Some section</a>
<div id="someSection">
  Some section below
</div>



Or just use a button that on the click event fires document.getElementById("createPost").scrollIntoView() with optionally setting behavior: "smooth" and/or block: "start". Check the mdn docs for reference on the options.

The input element inside an anchor is invalid HTML altogether.
